# cannot customize the icons using ng2-pdfjs-viewer

Tags: angular12, ng2-pdfjs-viewer, carbon-design-system

I am using ng2-pdfjs-viewer to display the pdf document. I use Angular version 12. I am able to customize its style in the viewer.css file under assets/pdfjs/web/viewer.css.

The design library which i am using in my project is carbon design system. I am trying to make use of the carbon components like search icon/arrow icon. I cannot get it working since i have the css and html files under the assets folder.

i am able to use carbon components in all other components but not in the files under assets folder. Is there a way to achieve this?
Any help/suggestion is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer! I had to have the carbon icons under `assets/pdfjs/web/images` and made use of those in the app. Problem solved.